# 1 function to replace innerHTML of 4 different ID independently

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I want a function that will replace the innerHTML of an element with an ID with a specific string depending on its own innerHTML. I currently have 4 elements with distinct IDs and I have a function of the sort for each of them. Since the 4 functions do the exact same thing and replace the innerHTML with the exact same strings depending on the same conditions, is it possible to make 1 function that will work for all elements at the same time instead of having 4? (Each function tests 160 different values, which means that they contain 160 `if` statements each... having 4 of them makes the code seem unnecessarily long)

Here is an example of the code (with 3 different conditions for each element instead of 160):

```
<body>

  <div id="object1">10</div>
  <div id="object2">10</div>
  <div id="object3">10</div>
  <div id="object4">10</div>

  <div id="extra1"></div>
  <div id="extra2"></div>
  <div id="extra3"></div>
  <div id="extra4"></div>

<script>

  function changeHTML1() {
    var ob1 = document.getElementById("object1");
    var ex1 = document.getElementById("extra1");
    if (ob1.innerHTML == "10") {
      ex1.innerHTML = "D5";
    }
    if (ob1.innerHTML == "9") {
      ex1.innerHTML = "1-D4";
    }
    if (ob1.innerHTML == "8") {
      ex1.innerHTML = "D4";
    }
  }

  function changeHTML2() {
    var ob2 = document.getElementById("object2");
    var ex2 = document.getElementById("extra2");
    if (ob2.innerHTML == "10") {
      ex2.innerHTML = "D5";
    }
    if (ob2.innerHTML == "9") {
      ex2.innerHTML = "1-D4";
    }
    if (ob2.innerHTML == "8") {
      ex2.innerHTML = "D4";
    }
  }

  function changeHTML3() {
    var ob3 = document.getElementById("object3");
    var ex3 = document.getElementById("extra3");
    if (ob3.innerHTML == "10") {
      ex3.innerHTML = "D5";
    }
    if (ob3.innerHTML == "9") {
      ex3.innerHTML = "1-D4";
    }
    if (ob3.innerHTML == "8") {
      ex3.innerHTML = "D4";
    }
  }

  function changeHTML4() {
    var ob4 = document.getElementById("object4");
    var ex4 = document.getElementById("extra4");
    if (ob4.innerHTML == "10") {
      ex4.innerHTML = "D5";
    }
    if (ob4.innerHTML == "9") {
      ex4.innerHTML = "1-D4";
    }
    if (ob4.innerHTML == "8") {
      ex4.innerHTML = "D4";
    }
  }

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your functions are currently *exactly* the same, why not delete all but one and refer to that one?

Comment: Sorry, I was copy-pasting similar parts of the code. Let me edit it so it’s correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this;

```
function changeHTML() {
  var i;
  var numberOfElements = 4;

  for (i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {         
    var ob = document.getElementById("object"+i);
    var ex = document.getElementById("extra"+i);

    if (ob.innerHTML == "10") {
      ex.innerHTML = "D5";
    }
    if (ob.innerHTML == "9") {
      ex.innerHTML = "1-D4";
    }
    if (ob.innerHTML == "8") {
      ex.innerHTML = "D4";
    }
 }    
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to make a higher-order function - a function to which you can pass the IDs of the object and extra in question:

```
const makeChangeHTML = (objSel, extSel) => {
  const ob = document.getElementById(objSel);
  const ex = document.getElementById(extSel);
  return () => {
    // do tests, assign to `ex`
```

But it would probably be easier if you used an *object* for the possible values of `object` and the corresponding value to go into the `extra`, rather than some very verbose if-statements:

```
const extraIndexedByObj = {
  '10': 'D5',
  '9': '1-D4',
  '8': 'D4',
};

const makeChangeHTML = (objId, extId) => {
  const ob = document.getElementById(objId);
  const ex = document.getElementById(extId);
  return () => {
    const { textContent } = ob;
    const extraVaue = extraIndexedByObj[textContent];
    if (extraVaue !== undefined) ex.textContent = extraVaue;
  }
}
```

Then you can create a function by calling `makeChangeHTML` with the appropriate selectors:

```
const change1 = makeChangeHTML('object1', 'extra1');
const change2 = makeChangeHTML('object2', 'extra2');
```

But, if it's possible, it would be nice to change your HTML as well - instead of using a separate ID for every single element, you might give each element a class name, and then relate the n-th `object` with the n-th `extra`. IDs aren't really appropriate here - for example:

```
<div class="object">10</div>
<div class="object">10</div>
<div class="object">10</div>
<div class="object">10</div>

<div class="extra"></div>
<div class="extra"></div>
<div class="extra"></div>
<div class="extra"></div>
```

And then select each pair so you can do whatever you need to do with them:

```
const objects = document.querySelectorAll('.object');
const extras = document.querySelectorAll('.extra');
objects.forEach((object, i) => {
  const extra = extras[i];
  // do something with each `object` and each `extra`
});
```

Comment: Yes, that idea of using an object instead of if-statements makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rethink the problem. Instead of using condition checks you can use an object.

```
var lookup = {
  "10" : "D5",
  "9" : "1-D4",
  "8" : "D4"
};

function doCheck(inElemId, outElemId) {
  var in = document.getElementById(inElemId);
  var out = document.getElementById(outElemId);

  var key = in.textContent.trim();

  if (lookup.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // the lookup object contains the 'key'
    out.textContent = lookup[key];
  }
}
```

If the element Ids are incremental numeric values you can use a loop.

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(ix) {
  doCheck('object'+ix, 'extra'+ix);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more scalable solution use querySelectorAll

```js
function changeHtml()
{
  //Get all elemtents which have an id that starts with "object"
  var sourceElements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='object']");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < sourceElements.length; i++)
  {
    var value = sourceElements[i].innerHTML;    
    var suffix = sourceElements[i].id.replace("object","");
    var target = document.getElementById("extra" + suffix);
    
    //A switch is better than multiple ifs
    //This could also be easily replace with an object based
    //solution similar to that in other answers.
    switch(value)
    {
      case "10":
        target.innerHTML = "D5";
        break;
      case "9":
        target.innerHTML = "1-D4";
        break;
      case "8":
        target.innerHTML = "D4";
        break;
    }
  }
  
}

changeHtml();
```

```html
 <div id="object1">10</div>
  <div id="object2">9</div>
  <div id="object3">8</div>
  <div id="object4">10</div>

  <div id="extra1"></div>
  <div id="extra2"></div>
  <div id="extra3"></div>
  <div id="extra4"></div>
```